# unity xcode simulator selected but no simulators listed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator, ios9

I recently started running into this issue where I build to the simulator SDK in Unity, but no simulators are listed for me to build to. The only option shown is "My Mac". I have the latest simulators downloaded (9.0-9.1) and that is my build target. I've tried in Xcode 7.1 and the 7.2 beta, and I'm using Unity 5.2.2. Any ideas as to what may cause/fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(1) In Unity select Simulator SDK.
(2) Build and run
(3) In Xcode , Build setting -> Architecture -> Supported platform -> select iOS.

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Unity, before building your project, go to: Player settings > Other settings > SDK version > Simulator SDK

Make sure simulator Sdk is checked and not Device Sdk.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

In unity to list out simulators flow the steps:-

1. Select Project From **Targets** of Project.
2. Go to **Builds Setting**.
3. Now Select iOS from **Supported Platforms** & **Base SDK** in Architecture Section of Build Settings.